# Infinite loop when trying to redirect

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

If I visit the page *search* (http://localhost:4200/search), I would like to get redirected to the homepage (http://localhost:4200).

I have this function in my file *login.guards.ts*:

```
  hasAccess() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.loginService.hasCookie(this.cookieService.get('login')).subscribe(hasCookie => {

          // User is not logged in
          console.log(this.location.path());
          if (this.location.path() === '/login' || this.location.path() === '/register' || this.location.path() === '') {
            return resolve(true);
          }
          return resolve(this.router.createUrlTree(['']));

        });
      });
    }
```

*app-routing.modules.ts:*

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'edit-profile', component: ProfileComponent }
];
```

My problem is, once I visit the */search* page, there is an infinite loop and I do not get redirected to the homepage. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you trying to redirect if the user has no access?

Comment: Login can activate login guard which will redirect to login which can activate to login guard which will redirect to login which can activate to login guard which will redirect to login which can activate to login guard which will redirect to login which can activate to login guard which will redirect to login which can activate to login guard which will redirect to login which can activate to login guard

Comment: @Arcteezy I am trying to redirect to the home page. It's http://localhost:4200.

Comment: This is your problem. When your user have no access, you redirect the route to home. But your `HomeComponent` is also guarded which will trigger the routing again and results in a loop. I don't get why you are trying to redirect to home. Isn't login the correct page for users with no access?

Comment: @Arcteezy my `HomeComponent` is guarded because I would like to redirect the user to the page */search* if they are already logged in.